# getActivity returns null in Fragment's onActivityCreated

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app works fine on most devices, except in some, where even in the fragment's **onActivityCreated**, the **getActivity** method keeps returning `null`. I need **Context** class to set-up things.

So anyone can help me?

### Example

```
public class BaseProductFragment extends Fragment {

...

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(layout_id, container,
            false);
    return rootView;
}

public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ImageCacheParams cacheParams = new ImageCacheParams(getActivity(),
            Utils.PRODUCTS_CACHE_DIR);
    ....
}
```

Comment: getActivity() returns null until onAttach() is called. Try to move this code to onAttach() method.

Answer (score 6):

`getActivity` "might" return `null` when called from within `onActivityCreated`...especially during a configuration change like orientation change because the activity gets destroyed...move that initialization to `onAttach`...

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    //initialize here
}
```

`onActivityCreated` is a called when the parent activity's `onCreate` is called...but remember that it could be "recreated", destroyed during a config change